# How can you get to level 2 without any farm?

Tags: league-of-legends

Last League of Legends game, I played Riven top and we had Lee jungle and so I didn't pull (red). Mundo came at about 2:10 from behind had 0 farm but was level 2. I tried to kill him and realised too late that he was level 2 and died to his ignite.

Would somebody be able to explain to me how you can get to level 2 without any farm?

Comment: I used to play HON, and you could get exp just by being beside an ally that kills mobs, just less than him. Maybe it's the same thing in LoL?

Comment: Supports do that on a daily basis.

Answer (score 11):

**EXP is granted based on being *near* a kill**, not being the one to kill it. Each monster/minion/champion grants EXP that is divided equally to all those who are in that area.

If he leashed jungle he could have stayed long and taken EXP when the jungler killed the camp. To be level 2 though probably means he took EXP from more than one camp however.

You didn't say who the other team's jungler was but what could have happened is this. Mundo helps their jungle steal your blue (Lee generally starts red and they took advantage of that) then he helped leash the enemy red after. Those camps should be enough to get both Mundo and the jungler to level 2

Comment: agreed more then one camp would have to been involved.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the answer, you get EXP from being near a kill, so if you are near a some minions and your friend kills about 5 or 6 you will get from level 1 to 2